# Add Different Actions To Different Page's wp_footer

Tags: hooks, actions, footer

I am trying to add functions to wp_footer based on the the page id. I am hooking my callback to `init`, but its not working. Here is what I am using.

```
function fl_template_loader() {

    if ( is_page( 1032 ) ) {
        add_action( 'wp_footer', 'fl_theme_midnight' );
    }
    if ( is_page( 1032 ) ) {
        add_action( 'wp_footer', 'fl_theme_passion' );
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'fl_template_loader', 0 );
```

What I am doing wrong? Is the `init` firing too early or too late? I tried to hook in `plugins_loaded` (for early execution) and `wp_loaded` (for later execution), but all failed.

Comment: Try using `wp` hook instead of 'init'.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use `wp_footer` action for that. And check your pages in functions itself to perform some specific tasks. something like this.

```
function my_footer_function() {

  if ( is_page( 1032 ) ) {

    // Do this

  } elseif ( is_page( 1033 ) ) {

    // Do that

  } else {

    // Do something else or nothing

  }

}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'my_footer_function', 100 );
```